# Update model sort order

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

```
public class SysAnalysis
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<PublicAnalysis> Analysis { get; set; }
}


public class PublicAnalysis 
{

  public Nullable<int>  AnalysisID { get; set; }
  public int TypeID { get; set; }  
}
```

I have the following code in my controller:

```
    model.PublicAnalysis.OrderBy(s => s.TypeID == 2).ThenBy(s => s.TypeID == 3).ThenBy(s => s.TypeID == 0).ThenBy(s => s.TypeID == 1);
    return PartialView("Partial/_AnalysisGrid", model);
```

The problem I am facing is that with the code above:

```
     model.PublicAnalysis.OrderBy(s => s.TypeID == 2).ThenBy(s => s.TypeID == 3).ThenBy(s => s.TypeID == 0).ThenBy(s => s.TypeID == 1);
```

it does not change the order of TypeID when I view it in model below. I was hoping it would rearrange it as such.

Comment: `OrderBy` _returns_ a new iterator; it does not sort the collection in-place. So you need `model.PublicAnalysis = model.PublicAnalysis.OrderBy(...`This has been answered many times before so I'll find a decent duplicate.

Comment: `return PartialView("Partial/_AnalysisGrid", model.OrderBy(s => s.TypeID == 2).ThenBy(s => s.TypeID == 3).ThenBy(s => s.TypeID == 0).ThenBy(s => s.TypeID == 1));`